# Create an arrow shape based on a vector

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

I've been trying to generate an arrow shape with javascript, which would have following characteristics:

- random direction
- random length (in bounds which doesn't matter in this question)
- the length of the arrow head would be specific (10% of the arrows length)
- the angle of the arrow head would be specific (30 degrees from the vector)

What I've managed to do so far is generating the line which always starts in point `(0,0)`, has random angle α and random length `l` both of which I know. I also have the coordinates of the ending point of the line `(x,y)`.

Now what is the most troubling part for me is creating the head arrow shape. I know one side of it would have to start in `(x,y)` point and be at 30 degree from the line, and the opposite would be the same just the but at -30 degree. So I guess what I would need is the ending point of each arrowhead side `(n,m) (n',m')` derived from the provided data?

I've never been good at maths, I've seen some helpfull equations but I'm afraid my brain doesn't have enough computing power to create a general case for this. If anyone could help that'd be great :)

[image]
my data:

- (x,y)
- L
- α

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give me one more piece of data, which I'll call $f$:

- $f$: a number between $0$ and $1$ indicating the length of the arrow "edges" as a fraction of $L$. If $f = 0.1$, then the edges of the arrowhead are each $10%$ of the length $L$ of the main body of the arrow.

I'll be writing "$+$" and "$-$" for points, and when I write those, I mean this: add or subtract term-by-term. So 
$$
(3, 5) + (-2, 4) = (3+ (-2), 5 + 4) = (1, 9),
$$
for instance. I'll also multiply ordered pairs by a number (in a process called "scalar multiplication"), again termwise, so that
$$
3(1, -4) = (3, -12). 
$$

Finally, since you've expressed angles in degrees, I'll express them in degrees as well, and when I write $\cos (30)$, I'll assume that this means the cosine of 30 degrees (which may be computed in your programming language using something like `cosd(330)`, or may have to computed by something like 
`u = cos (30. * PI/180.)`, where `PI` is a constant that you've defined to be approximately `3.14159265`. I'm not willing to read the Javascript manual to figure out how that particular language does it, because that's not math -- it's programming.

Finally, I'm going to assume that I can write `draw(P, Q)`, where `P` and `Q` are points of the plane, to draw a line segment from one to the other.

There's one last thing: you've called the two new points $(n, m)$ and $(n', m')$, which I dislike. I'm going to call them $(a, b)$ and $(u, v)$.

Let's do it, in pseudo-code:

```
E = L * (cos(alpha), sin(alpha)) // the arrow-end
S = (0.0, 0.0)  // the arrow-start
draw(S, E)      // the arrow shaft

beta = -alpha + 30 // the direction from the arrowhead to 
                // the tip-end that's clockwise from it
v = f*L*(cos(beta), sin(beta)) // the vector from the shaft-end
                         // towards the first tip
P = E + v       // the first tip
draw(E, P)

// Now repeat for the other tip
beta = -alpha - 30 // the direction from the arrowhead to 
                // the tip-end that's COUNTERclockwise from it
                // (note the minus sign)
v = f*L*(cos(beta), sin(beta)) // the vector from the shaft-end
                         // towards the second tip
Q = E + v       // the second tip
draw(E, Q)
```

And that's it.